# Programmatically navigate using React router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

With react-router I can use the Link element to create links which are natively handled by react router.

I see internally it calls this.context.transitionTo(...).

I want to do a navigation. Not from a link, but from a dropdown selection (as an example). How can I do this in code? What is this.context?

I saw the Navigation mixin, but can I do this without mixins?

Comment: You have to use the `useNavigate` hook.

Comment: If you are wanting to use `react-router-dom` the official docs are pretty useful. Start with the overview and tutorial: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Put it anywhere in a function.

```
navigate("/url");
```